# Bean validation using a custom @RequiredWhen validator and required field decorator in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, bean-validation

I have defined a custom jsr-303-Validator called `@RequiredWhen` which is like `@NotNull` but depending on some condition.

In JSF, whenever I annotate a managed bean property with `@NotNull` a component like PrimeFaces `<p:outputLabel for="that property">`, recognizes the property as required and marks it with an asterisk. Is it possible to implement or configure my custom Validator such that the asterisk is shown as well, if the condition in the `@RequiredWhen`-annotation becomes true? Thanks a lot.

I'm using,

- Java EE 6
- GlassFish 3.1.2
- Mojarra 2.1.29
- PrimeFaces 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see by now the answer is no: it's not possible to show the asterix by configuring or implementing the custom validator. Looking at the sources of primefaces the check for @NotNull is hardcoded and there is no kind of callback to check for other annotations.

As a first workaround we added a new bean that checks an input field for our custom annotations, eg

```
<p:inputText id="test" value="#{uiController.data}" 
         required="#{ContextValidatorDelegate.isRequired('data')}"/>
```

But after some closer look we removed that delegate. The condition in our custom validator is dependend on properties that the user can modify in the same dialog than the property that is validated. So our validator really is some class level validator. And thus we cannot use the required-attribute, which is processed in validation phase. We need the complete user-input in our model bean. Only after the update model phase a class level validation is meaningful.

Comment: Why not create an enhanced version of the PrimeFaces class? One that just checks for your annotation to. It is java and you can override it easily

Comment: Well, our customer bought primefaces pro, the supported version. Therefore changes "in" primefaces is a no go. So we were looking for some way "outside" primefaces to implement our requirement. On the other hand once understanding that we are actually working with class level validators where the user changes the conditions on the validation outcome in his dialog, we decided that the asterix is misleading. We dropped that feature.